# Integrate Cakephp username and password for a php script

Tags: php, cakephp, hash, passwords, sha1

I am currently working on a PHP Project where i need to integrate user information from a CakePHP driven website.

CakePHP using the following method for password encryption:

```
Security::hash($user['User']['password'],null,true);
```

I know, CakePHP By default use the SHA1 encryption method.

i have tried to encrypt a password using SHA1 by using PHP but i come to know that is not matching with cakePHP encryption.

```
    <?php
    $str = 'apple';

    if (sha1($str) === 'd0be2dc421be4fcd0172e5afceea3970e2f3d940') {
        echo "login info found?";
    }
else{

echo "No info found";

}
    ?>
```

if any one has a solution. please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your 3rd argument is true, CakePHP will salt the hash with the value stored in your configuration: 
`$string = Configure::read('Security.salt') . $string;` 
See http://api.cakephp.org/view_source/security#line-91

Comment: ok, how can i retrieve the correct password? please give an example.

Comment: Give this a run:
`<form action="<? echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">`
`<input type="password" name="password" />`
`<input type="submit" value="Submit" />`
`</form>`
`<?php`
`if(!isset($_POST['password'])){exit;}`
`$hashStoredInDatabase="c2dd61147961759b58ca05c3ef3054f0e9cb4bfc";`
`$saltStoredInDatabase="ed304955";`
`if(sha1($saltStoredInDatabase.$_POST['password'])==$hashStoredInDatabase)`
`{`
`echo "Passwords match!";`
`}else{`
`echo "Passwords Didn't match!";`
`}`
`exit;`
`?>`
The password is `apple`.

Comment: Once you got that working update the IF statement to instead use: `if(Security::hash($_POST['password'],null,$saltStoredInDatabase)==$hashStoredInDatabase)`